# How am i supposed to download an older version of Ubuntu

Tags: downloads

Im confused looking for an older version of Ubuntu, i know that you can download it using bittorrents but is there any other way, just by desktop downloading. I just want desktop ubuntu 16.04 version. not the latest one.

Answer (score 2):

http://releases.ubuntu.com/ contains every active release, which currently goes back to 12.04.5.

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ contains everything from 4.10 to 17.10, including unsupported releases.